# PhpStorm debugger does not jump in target php files while debugging

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, xdebug, yii2-advanced-app

I have created a Yii2 application using Docker containers, that I want to debug.  Using the zero-configuration debugging [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html) I was able to easily start a debugging session, by simply activating the 'listening' icon and capturing the external communication using .

[image]

Debugging is working fine but I have noticed a strange behavior on the IDE while debugging.

I have placed a breakpoint on line #3 of `frontend/index.php`. As expected, when I display the page, the breakpoint is hit.

[image]

By clicking on <kbd>F8</kbd>, I can step over the code but when I arrive at line #17 and click on <kbd>F7</kbd> (stepping into), it seems that the debugger still does its job by continuing its way through the code (as you can notice in the 'Frames' panel), but usually, the IDE should open the target file, and show the progression in the code, but its not.

If I keep clicking on <kbd>F8</kbd>, files and methods on the 'frames' panel will keep changing but the only file that the IDE will show is index.php

[image]

One other thing that I have noticed is the warning in 'Variables' panel:

> Remote file path `app.../BaseYii.php` is not mapped to any file path in project

Should I manually map every file in the project??? Hope not...

This is probably nothing complicated, but I'm stuck.

Does anyone have a clue?

Here is my Server Settings screen.

[image]

How do I map to project root?

Comment: No, you do not need to map every file (children will inherit mapping from parent folder). Based on your description it sounds like initial mapping is done on a bit lower level (`frontend` folder) while Yii code is in folder that is outside of it. If that's so -- just fix the mapping manually -- `Settings/Preferences | Language & Frameworks | PHP | Server` -- if not sure, post your the screenshot here. But in general -- just have a mapping for the project root -- it does the job in almost all cases.

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. I have added my Settings screen

Comment: Just map your `C:\Users\Francois\Projects\myms-demo` to `/app` -- that should be it. Then you can even remove that existing mapping for `/app/frontend/web` (as it will be inherited from parent.

Comment: P.S. Project folder name on your first screenshot and last one differs (`tadv` vs `myms-demo`)  .. but I assume those are 2 diff projects...

Comment: Sorry, this was an old image from a procedure I wrote yesterday.  I will update it to make sure it does not confuse anybody.

Comment: IT WORKS!  Thank you very much! I now can enter other files while debugging!

Comment: I have tried to delete the B-END server to test if I could only have one Server entry point (F-END), while entering backend/index.php, but it kept asking me to setup a new 'Incoming Connection From Xdebug'.  If there is no way to just have one entry point, I can live with two, no problem... ;-)

Comment: Show screenshots for that screen for both entries -- there must be some difference there (e.g. different port numbers used etc) otherwise 1 entry should be just fine for both back-end and front-end code.

Comment: Yes exactly, frontend is accessed using 192.168.99.101:20080 and backend using 192.168.99.101:21080.  So I will leave it like that.

Comment: How can I set your intervention has the answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I manually map every file in the project??? Hope not...

No, you do not need to map every file (children will inherit mapping from parent folder).

---

Based on your description it sounds like initial mapping is done on a bit lower level (`frontend` folder) while Yii code is in folder that is outside of it. If that's so then just fix the mapping manually at `Settings/Preferences | Language & Frameworks | PHP | Servers`.

Based on your `Servers` screenshot you to map your `C:\Users\Francois\Projects\myms-demo` (project root folder) to `/app` and that's it. You can then remove that existing mapping for `/app/frontend/web` later (as it will be inherited from the parent and therefore is unnecessary).

```
C:\Users\Francois\Projects\myms-demo <--> /app
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much LazyOne for your help!

I surely would not solved this problem in one day without you.

The solution to this problem is that, right after **capturing Incoming Connection from Xdebug**, you should go to **Servers** configuration page (*File/Settings…, and Languages & Frameworks/PHP/Servers*), delete the entry found in **Absolute path on the server** for the **web** directory and replace it by **/app** on the project root directory (here *C:\Users\Francois\Projects\myms-demo*).

Doing so will enable you to debug all php files in the project.

There is a little complication level when you are using Yii2 Advanced Application (YAA). the YAA is composed of a backend and a frontend application within the same project folder. Unless you works with vhosts on DEV side, you will need, when installed by docker-compose, to access your applications using ports.

Frontend is accessed using 192.168.99.101:20080 and Backend using 192.168.99.101:21080.

This is the reason you will need to have two server entry points with respective mapping to project root directory.